# Does get_delete_post_link() delete the post's meta in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `get_delete_post_link()` on the front-end of my website which allows blog post authors to delete their posts.

My question is, when this link is used to delete a post, does the post meta get deleted also?

Hoping somebody can help explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using it without any argument, then post will be moved into trash. Trashed post do keep post meta.

But if you supply the third argument to true, then post will be permanently delete including meta informations.

```
// first argument post_id
// second one deprecated 
// third one is force_delete, which deletes post permanently including post meta.
get_delete_post_link(null, '', true);
```

Comment: Hi Shazzad - thanks for your reply. So, if I pass true, the post gets permanently deleted. How about the post's meta? does that get deleted too? Can you point me in the direction of where this is documented? I'd like to read up on it. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it deletes post meta too. ref: file `wp-includes/link-template.php` on line `956` for WP 3.8

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't the function starting on line 954 just show how the link is built? From that, I'm wondering how post meta is deleted?

Comment: The generated link by `get_delete_post_link()` takes you to wp-admin page with some query variables `nonce, post & action`. The request is handled by `wp-admin/edit.php` file on `line 122(+-)`. Then after checking the post type and existence, another function called `wp_delete_post()` with post_id, function reference `wp-includes/post.php` `line 2290(+-)`.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Thanks again!